# How to analyze the audio file recorded in audio queue services in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, audioqueueservices

I know the file path. How am I going to open it? I want the LPCM format like the one in the buffer when recording the audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the iOS Extended Audio File Serveces API to read the uncompressed audio samples.

Answer (score 0):

AudioGraph is a good, working example:

https://github.com/tkzic/audiograph